# Choice of quick-connect connectors

Tags: connector

I am trying to connect 22 AWG wire via quick-connect connectors to a solenoid pump of which the terminals are 6 mm wide. I thought a 6. 3mm spade connector should do the job but the online marketplace posting offering the same say its for 14-16 AWG. How to make a choice? Must it say 22 AWG or would 22 AWG fit even there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get different combinations of tab size and ferrule size. If the quick-connect terminal you are looking at says 14-16A WG it will not fit 22 AWG wire. The most common 6.3m m spade will not fit 22 AWG. You need a 6. 3mm quick-connect connector made for 22 AWG wire. You won't find them hanging on the shelf in the hardware store but they do exist. Search Mouser or Digikey for examples.